# Push to a git repository from TFS build process

Tags: git, tfs, build, kudu

I am looking to use https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu to automate our deployments. I have Kudu all set up and working nicely.

However I want to be able to push to the git repository from a TFS build. I have looked at the existing build template in TFS and had a play with the lovely XAML.

Can someone provide a simple example of pushing to git or executing an executable in TFS?

Comment: How did you manage to achieve this? did you have to Git Init a new repository and then push it into kudu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call an executable then add the InvokeProcess activity to your build workflow. You can then call your Git package exe and perform the needed push.
[InvokeProcess Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_InvokeProcess)

[image: Properties to set]

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to "call your Git package exe and perform the needed push"?

Comment: In the question the person is thinking of using Kudu. Click on the link for more details but basically once everything is setup you just need to call a cmd line script from the tfs process. That is why the invoke process will work and allow any commands to be called. i.e. from the command line something like this ........... cmd                                                                  git push azure master                                                 Hope this helps answer your quesiton.

Comment: yes, but the TFS build is not a Git repository itself, I am initializing one and then pushing into Git and I'm wondering if there is a better way

Comment: Correct, but the code being pulled down in this instance is a website , so the user is using it as a deployment trigger via TFS build since website code has already been pulled down via the TFS build process